# Google Chrome Extension + chrome.windows.create + window.getSelection().toString()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension which copies the selected/highlighted text into a textarea. This is what I used so far:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();",
}, function(selection) {
    document.getElementById("output").value = selection[0];
});
```

But now I've switched from the popup.html to a window which I created like this

**background.js**:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("window.html"),
        type: "panel", height: 590, width:850, focused: false
        }, function(win) {
    });
});
```

And I can't get the selected text into this window anymore. I also copied the current URL of the activetab doing like so:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(windowId, function(tab) {
    document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = tab.url;
    var windowId = tab.id
});
```

and I could make this work for the new window using:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = tabs[0].url;
});
```

So my question is: **How can I get the selected/highlighted text into the textarea inside my newly created window?** Is there something similiar to the

```
chrome.tabs.query()
```

just for highlighted text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use executeScript's tabId parameter to inject in the clicked tab, then pass the text using any of these:

- [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)
- [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)
- [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in the URL: `'window.html?url=' + encodeURIComponent(text)`
  then in window.js use decodeURIComponent.
- localStorage, the classic synchronous storage shared between all internal extension pages, in case you need the result appear on the first page render without delay/flicker and don't want to pass the text in URL.

Here's an example for localStorage.

- background.js:

  ```
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      getSelectedText(tab.id, function(text) {
          localStorage.selectedText = text;
          chrome.windows.create({
              url: "/window.html",
              type: "panel", height: 590, width:850, focused: false
          });
      });
  });

  function getSelectedText(tabId, cb) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
          code: "window.getSelection().toString();",
      }, function(selection) {
          cb(selection[0]);
      });
  }
  ```
- window.html:

  ```html
          .................
          <script src="window.js"></script>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```
- window.js:

  ```
  document.getElementById('url').textContent = localStorage.selectedText || '';
  delete localStorage.selectedText;
  ```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed.